# Express : router object and methods

Tags: javascript, express, router

I have

```
 var router = express.Router(); 

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
       //something
    }

   module.exports = router;
```

Is the router created, the get method executed and the router exported, or is it that the router is created, the method is define for this router (not executed) and the router is exported afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second one. Router is created, method is defined and router is exported. That method will be executed when browser sends get request on '/' url, if you correctly require exported router.

Comment: What is the name of the method. If I want to use it in another file, how can I call the get function. For example, I want to call router.get('/'). What is the name and the arguments of the function ?

Comment: Only way to call function is sending request to the given route, for this example "/". You can create function which might be used in many route for example: function myFunc (req, res) {}, and use it in many routes like: router.get( "/", myFunc), router.get("/users", myfunc); Arguments must be at least req(request), res(response). Please look at expressjs documentation. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html